# div out of body with bigger width

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm fairly new to frontend so sorry if this is a rookie mistake. I want to create a div out of my body with bigger width (all available width) but don't know how.

I have a personal webpage at https://jiwidi.github.io/ where the body is centered with a fixed width. This works for me when having blog/text pages but I also want to add a photos section https://jiwidi.github.io/photos/ in which I would like to make the photos go out of this body and create a gallery with full screen width, something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_grid_responsive. Right now my pictures are limited to the body width and don't create the gallery look I want.

My problem is that I dont even know what modification to the style / html structure should I begin with. Is this a good practice? Any advice on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a div inside the body with your current content and then make another div in the body for the gallery. And just set the body width to 100%

Comment: Hi, I did like you said and I managed to keep original style and have the image gallery use full width. Now my div that has the gallery goes on top of the div with the original content (takes all screen space and seems like the background of the web), any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: I can't really help you without any images and code

Comment: That's a cool page but yes we will probably need some code. However have you tried setting the css for the div to `width: 100vw;` and also the `left` property to a negative value (so it's centered again)

Comment: Also idk if it is just my firefox but when I try to use `cd github` it gives me a `pop up blocked` message and doesn't open the site, but it works fine if I just click the link

Comment: @FireFighter sorry for not appending example last comment, you can check the div missplacement here now https://jiwidi.github.io/photos/

Comment: @RolvApneseth Thanks! I will look into that, cd github should open the github url so I guess is some browser ad security blocking it.

Comment: You have the the intro div set to `position: fixed` so either set it to `position: relative` to push the gallery down, or for the gallery section, set `padding-top: x` where x is the height of the intro div. In scss I would do this with a variable but for example setting `padding-top: 10rem` for the gallery section pushes the gallery down enough to not be the background for the intro. I realise you want to keep the intro at the top of the page so probably that second thing is what you're looking for